How can I create a Github action that runs on Release creation to update the repo, before the release is generated?
As per the title, we have a repo on Github that has some translations in it.  These translations though are for 3rd party error codes, which get updated every time they update their infrastructure.
There is an API we can use to pull all of the latest error codes and associated transactions, however, we cannot do this in our software, but need to do it when we generate a new release.
Is there a way we can generate a GitHub action that runs when we create a release, updates the repo with the new translations, and then finalizes the release and generates the source file zips?
